# opening a very long url in tmux terminal

Tags: tmux

I have a problem with opening very long URL in tmux. In my case the URL is longer than a line and tmux break it into multiple lines. However when I use mouse to click on the URL, it only opens the first line of the URL and ignore the rest.

I am just wondering how I can change my tmux config to support this use case.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on how exactly your URLs appears on the screen.

If you just print out the lines as it naturally happens (e.g. with `cat` command), the lines get joined and the URLs can actually be clicked.

However, if you use `vim` or `less` or another viewer, they try to show the text line by line and it's actually the software to break the lines.

With `less`, the action that helps is: scroll back one screen with `b` and forward with `space`.

With `vim` something like `:w !cat` can help.

In other words, you should think of a way to just naturally print the URL so that it would wrap over the screen border.

Needless to say, your screen should occupy the full terminal width, i.e. ***not*** split vertically.

To temporary remove all other panes, there's 'zoom' for panes in tmux: activated by `C-b z`.

Comment: For some folks Prefix may be Ctrl+A or Ctrl+Space, but the 'zoom' for panes is the workaround I use the most as well. 

Another trick from a tmux plugin for handling URLs and text is to highlight what you can on the first line in copy mode, then hit <kbd>e</kbd> until the rest of the URL is highlighted, then you can yank <kbd>Enter</kbd> and open using `xdg-open` the URL after pasting with Prefix+p (if mapped). https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-copycat/issues/59